# Disabling CORS(cross-origin resource sharing) on the Mobile device - Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cors

I have created an Ionic App which communicates with a middleware server based REST API. The App performs user authentication. So that I can test the app in the browser (Google Chrome), I have been installed the Chrome extension called `CORS`and I have activated the extension every time when I wanted to test the user authentication in the browser. It worked well. Now I have installed the app on the device and my user authentication no longer works. But I have found so a setting:

```
{
  "name": "proxy-example",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

This setting should be saved in the `ionic.project` file. But I don't unterstand it well. What is actually `path` and `proxyUrl`. which url shuold I put for `proxyUrl`? The endpoint(link) of the authentification link? 
So that my User authentication also works on the device, what should I do?

Comment: you should set the accept header in the server. Ask to activate a plugin in a customer device is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `ionic.project` file should reside in the root directory of your project. (Alongside `www/`)

1. `path` - The request prefix that you have to specify to forward all such request requests to your `proxyUrl`.
2. `proxyUrl` - The actual url of your REST API.

After you successfully add the ionic.project file and re-build your project, this should work.

Example:

path to REST API: `http://example.com/api/`,

then setting `path`: `/api` and `proxyUrl`: `http://example.com/api/` will forward all requests from your application to the specified proxyUrl which begin with `/api`

Comment: Yes, I set `"path": "/api"` and `"proxyUrl": "http://myRestApi/api"` But I get error on the device via remote debugging: `POST http://myRestApi 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: My endpoint looks like the following example: `https://www.abctest.com/testmiddleware/middleware.php` How should actually look like the `path` and `proxyUrl` now?

Comment: You would set `path`: `https://www.abctest.com/testmiddleware/`, `proxyUrl`: `/testmiddleware` and your request url as : `/testmiddleware/middleware.php`

Comment: I still get the same error with the code `{
  "name": "proxy-test",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "https://www.abctest.com/testmiddleware/",
      "proxyUrl": "/testmiddleware"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: @Ramosta Sorry for the delay. Could you please with more specific with the error you are getting ?